# Eloquent hasMany relation without id

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I to count how many registration exist from the same nation.
So far, I came um with the following solution:
Method inside the Controller:

```php
class Camp extends Model // ...
{
    protected $with = ['registrations_nation_count',...];
    // ...

    public function registrations_nation_count()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CampRegistration::class)
            ->select(['camp_id','nation',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')])
            ->groupBy('nation');
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
      "registrations_nation_count": [
            {
                "camp_id": 1,
                "nation": "en",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "camp_id": 1,
                "nation": "fr",
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
```

Now I would like to remove the camp_id column from the output. I already tried to simply remove it from the select but this leads to no output at all. 
Is there any way to hide it?

Database:

```
+-------+--------------------+
| camps | camp_registrations |
+-------+--------------------+
| id    | id                 |
| ...   | camp_id            |
|       | nation             |
|       | ...                |
+-------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like :

```php
$camp->registrations_nation_count->makeHidden('camp_id');
```

After using 'with'

Comment: Yes. It results in an empty output. `"registrations_nation_count": []`

Comment: Ah, is this method registrations_nation_count() inside your camp model?

Comment: Yes,exactly. I edited the question and added the class definition and important variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't not-select the columns that are used to query the relation. In your example, this is the parent model's `id` and related model's `camp_id`.

I would strongly advise against having a `->select([..])` columns in the relationship definition. It will unnecessarily limit the use of the relationship.

Instead, you should omit the columns in some sort of transformer (such [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)) that transforms the resource for the end-user to see.

Comment: I understand the concept behind resources but how can I count all registrations with same nation without using select?